# System of differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{equation}
\dot{x}(t)=\left(1-\frac{x(t)}{E_{0}}\right) x(t) - a\ y(t)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dot{y}(t)=\left(1-\frac{a\ y(t)}{x(t)}\right) y(t)
\end{equation}

I am trying to solve the system of differential equations above, but (I think) it is nontrivial to calculate its solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the first equation for $y$, substitute into the second.  You get a second-order differential equation for $x(t)$:

$$ - \left( {\frac {d^{2}}{d{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right)  \right) x
 \left( t \right) {E_{{0}}}^{2}+ \left( {\frac {d}{dt}}x \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}{E_{{0}}}^{2}- \left( x \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{3}E_{{0}}+ \left( x \left( t \right)  \right) ^{4}
=0$$

Maple solves this explicitly:
$$x \left( t \right) =4\,{\frac {{{\rm e}^{ta+b}}{a}^{2}{E_{{0}}}^{2}}{-
4\,{a}^{2}{E_{{0}}}^{2}+{{\rm e}^{2\,ta+2\,b}}+4\,{{\rm e}^{ta+b}}E_{{0
}}+4\,{E_{{0}}}^{2}}}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants.

Comment: The solution $(x(t),y(t))=(E_0,0)$ corresponds to the limit $a=1$, $b\to-\infty$.